# how can i cover Private Method in Test Cases

Tags: apex

I have private method in class but how can i cover this  code

```
private static void HandleAfterInsert_IntObject_ReqCompRelations(map<Id,Integration__c>receivedReqCompRelations)
```

Comment: Post your code so that will be able to analyse from where you invoke private method in your class

Comment: **@TestVisible** before method definition would allow to call it from test class as well

Comment: The best way is via one of the public methods; a private method is usually just a building block used to achieve the public method behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can add @testvisible before your private method or variable.
Community can help you better if you post your code also.